# Start to Finish Advanced Project Tutorials

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Can anyone recommend some start to finish project tutorials that really emphasize good design principles and best practices. I am looking for things that demonstrate and emphasize any or all of these:

- Domain Driven Design
- Unit Testing
- Inversion of Control
- Separation of Concerns
- Use of interfaces
- Object Relational Mapping
- Preferably ASP.NET MVC

I am currently watching [the Autumn of Agile series](http://www.autumnofagile.net/), which demonstrates many of these principles. I would like to find more of these tutorials/demos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jason Dentler's [Using the N* stack](http://jasondentler.com/blog/2009/08/how-to-using-the-n-stack-part-1/) tutorial is quite comprehensive using a number of technologies (NHibernate, Ninject, jQuery) with ASP MVC.

Answer (score 5):

While not a project tutorial, I would suggest you take a look at JP Boodhoo's Nothing but .NET training. I'm pretty sure it touches on everything you're interested in (plus a lot more).

http://www.jpboodhoo.com/training.oo

Answer (score 2):

There are loads of nice tutorials + books about good codebase/design quality. But to me the real essence is how the codebase evolves (the history of a codebase). Codebase state A often is achievable and can have a clean design. IMO the real art of software developing is how you get to a codebase state B,C...Z and still keep the design and concepts consistent and clean.

Such tutorials are very rare, because it needs insights to the history of requirements and team behaviour, which adds a lot of complexity to "just" learn inside one tutorial.

But a good practice for improving desing during software evolution I can recommend is [Refactoring Workbook](http://www.amazon.de/Refactoring-Workbook-Addison-Wesley-Object-Technology/dp/0321109295/ref=sr_1_18?ie=UTF8&s=books-intl-de&qid=1275426328&sr=8-18).